# R function to calculate SSE for loess span optimisation - can't find error in code

Tags: r, optimization, loess

The code comes from http://r-statistics.co/Loess-Regression-With-R.html, and it is exactly what I would need, if I could only make it work.
Data:

```
data(economics, package="ggplot2") 
economics$index <- 1:nrow(economics)
economics <- economics[1:80, ]
```

Function to calculate SSE:

```
calcSSE <- function(x){
  loessMod <- try(loess(uempmed ~ index, data=economics, span=x), silent=T)
  res <- try(loessMod$residuals, silent=T)
  if(class(res)!="try-error"){
    if((sum(res, na.rm=T) > 0)){
      sse <- sum(res^2)  
    }
  }else{
    sse <- 99999
  }
  return(sse)
}
```

Finding out the best 'span' value for loess:

```
optim(par=c(0.5), calcSSE, method="SANN")
```

The problem is that this should yield a span of 0.0543 and an achievable minimum SSE of 3.85e-28 for a function count of 10000 (this can be checked at the link at the beginning of this post), but if I run it, it gives 0.5, SSE 99999 and the function count is only 2, so it obviously isn't working.

I am running R 4.1.2 under Win10 from RStudio. The only thing I can think of is that something major in R has been changed since this code was written. Any help in fixing it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The code at the link is not reproducible because it did not use `set.seed`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is here: `if((sum(res, na.rm=T) > 0)){` - this unnecessarily triggers a move to `sse <- 99999` when the sum of the residuals could quite reasonably be below zero.  If you remove that condition, then you get a more reasonable answer.  The `try()` function should catch any wonky stuff going on in the results.

```r
data(economics, package="ggplot2") 
economics$index <- 1:nrow(economics)
economics <- economics[1:80, ] 


calcSSE <- function(x){
  loessMod <- try(loess(uempmed ~ index, data=economics, span=x), silent=T)
  res <- try(loessMod$residuals, silent=T)
  if(!inherits(res, "try-error")){
      sse <- sum(res^2)  
  }else{
    sse <- 99999
  }
  return(sse)
}

optimize(calcSSE, c(0.01,1))
#> $minimum
#> [1] 0.04414211
#> 
#> $objective
#> [1] 7.888609e-31
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Note that I used `optimize` instead of `optim` because that's suggested if there is only one parameter being optimized.  I also removed the warnings from the output.  One other note, I switched `class(res)!="try-error"` to `!inherits(res, "try-error")` as this is encouraged because classes can often have more than one value.